# Inject JS only on specific tab on Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

*Sorry in advantage for my english.*

---

I am creating my first Chrome extension and I want to inject JS only on a specific tab.

This is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My description",
  "homepage_url": "http://example.com",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

Additionally, I have 2 files `background.js` and `inject.js`.

`Inject.js` can be what ever I want to inject, example:

```
(function() {
    console.log('Live is good');
})();
```

I think my issue is with the `background.js` file. I can manually inject the `inject.js` file in a specific tab when the user clicks on the extension button by using this code on the `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

Also, I can automatically inject the code on `inject.js` when the user update (refresh or change URL) the tab using this code on the `background.js` file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

The issue with the first option is that I need to click every time I want to inject the code, the issue with the second one is that the code is injected on **ANY** tab that is updated.

What I want is that the fist time, I need to click to inject it and then I want the code to be injected automatically only if the updated tab is the same where active tab when the user clicked.

This is my try (not working):

```
// listen for our browerAction to be clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({indexTabId: tab.id}, function() {
      console.log("The color is green.");
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    if ( chrome.storage.sync.get ( 'indexTabId', data ){
        if ( data.indexTabId == tab.id ) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
                file: 'inject.js'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `chrome.storage.sync.get` correctly, to the point of a syntax error.

```js
if ( chrome.storage.sync.get ( 'indexTabId', data ){
    if ( data.indexTabId == tab.id ) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });
    }
});
```

The outer `if` doesn't make much sense; your actual decision-making happens inside, so let's throw it out:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get ( 'indexTabId', data ){
    if ( data.indexTabId == tab.id ) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });
    }
}
```

This is still not the correct syntax for *calling* a function. You mix it up with syntax of defining a function. In general, [it should have](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-get) the following form:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get ( query, callback );
```

But you can define the callback right there as an anonymous function, like this:

```js
function ( items ) { /* code */ }
```

Or even like this, in ES6 fashion:

```js
( items ) => { /* code */ }
```

So, let's combine those:

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get ( 'indexTabId', function ( data ) {
    if ( data.indexTabId == tab.id ) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
            file: 'inject.js'
        });
    }
});
```

That should work now (put inside the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener` callback)

Comment: The problem with that is that `tab.id` does not exist on the line `if ( data.indexTabId == tab.id ) {`

Comment: It should; you get it from `onUpdated`. But you can also use `tabId` directly.

Comment: My code is still supposed to be wrapped up in `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener`

Comment: Well, with the wrap it works. Thanks (update the answer if you want, anyway, maked as the right solution). Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, added a note to that effect. As general advice, get a code editor (or plugin for one) that can analyze JavaScript code. Catching those kinds of errors by static analysis / linting is very helpful.